# Exporting all object Values as Keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm trying to export all object values as keys, in order to provide a tree-shakable import system for a plugin that I'm working on. I'm dynamically importing modules from folders and subfolders and putting them together in a giant object like this:

##### Object Structure

The structure of the object would be something like this:

```
components = {
   "MyPluginModule1": {...},
   "MyPluginModule2": {...},
   ...
   "MyPluginModule10000": {...},
}
```

The number of keys can be quite a lot and I certainly cannot export them one by one manually.

##### Tried Approach

I was trying to import the modules automatically from the directories (this works), but now the challenge is to export them.

```
const components = {};

// Now I dynamically import modules from different directories and add them in components

export {components};
```

However with this approach, I need to use `import {components} from "..."`. Then I can access `MyPluginModule1` as `components. MyPluginModule1`.

##### What's Needed

What I'd need is to be able to import `MyPluginModule1` directly without needed to import the entire `components` array and then accessing this particular module through `components.MyPluginModule1`.

Goal is to import like this:

```
import { MyPluginModule1 } from "...";
```

Comment: `export components;` It's not clear why you're exporting an object with a `components` property.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: `export components;` has the same result as `export {components};`. The object properties are not destructured  and remains inside `components`

Answer (score 0):

you can probably do this:

```
export * from components;
```